# Why can't I scanf and printf an integer?

Tags: c++, c, printf, user-input, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    int age;
    string name[20], dob[20], pob[20], gender[7];
};

int main ()
{
    person person[10];
    cout << "Please enter your name, date of birth, place of birth, gender, and age, separated by a space.\nFor example, John 1/15/1994 Maine Male 20: ";
    scanf("%s %s %s %s %d", &person[0].name, &person[0].dob, &person[0].pob, &person[0].gender, &person[0].age);
    printf("%s %s %s %s %d", &person[0].name, &person[0].dob, &person[0].pob, &person[0].gender, &person[0].age);
    return 0;
}
```

I try to scan and print the user's age but it gives me 2749536 for the `person.age` value. Why is that?

Comment: use `%f` for floats. Or define age like `int age;`

Comment: Use `cin` and `cout` (which you already do once at the beginning), and don't tag the question with C if you are using C++ features that can't be used in C (`iostream`, `cout`, `using namespace`, etc.)

Comment: I meant to write int. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot use scanf to read into `std::string`s.

Comment: @johnny880: In your `printf` calls, you are writing out the value of the pointer, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, change `string` to `char` in the declaration of `person`:

```
struct person
{
    int age;
    char name[20], dob[20], pob[20], gender[7];
//  ^^^^
};
```

Then you need to remove ampersand from `&person[0].age` in the call to `printf`, because you are passing an address of the `int`, not its value. Also remove ampersands from strings in `scanf` and `printf` calls:

```
scanf("%s %s %s %s %d", person[0].name, person[0].dob, person[0].pob, person[0].gender, &person[0].age);
// Only one ampersand is needed above: -------------------------------------------------^
printf("%s %s %s %s %d", person[0].name, person[0].dob, person[0].pob, person[0].gender, person[0].age);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/SZchRU)

Comment: Now it fixes the "2749536" but when I enter a "20", it prints out 0.

Comment: @johnny880 What values do you enter? Do they contain spaces?

Comment: I enter exactly this without the quotes: "John 1/15/1994 Maine Male 20"

Comment: Nevermind, it works now. I just forgot to change the float to int in the program itself. But now the program crashes.

Comment: @johnny880 That's because you used `string` instead of `char` for strings inside your `struct`. Fixing this problem makes the program run (see demo).

Answer (score 3):

You should change the type of `age` from `float` to `int`.

Otherwise, use `%f` for `float` type.

Also, as suggested by [Mr. dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight), change the `string` to `char`.

Then, remove the `&` from `&person[0].age` in case of `printf()`. You want to print the value of the variable, not the address. FWIW, to print an address, you should use `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `(void *)`.

DO NOT mix them up and expect them to work. If you supply improper type of arguments to the supplied format specifiers, it will eventually will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

*Moral of the story: Enable compiler warnings. Most of the time, they will warn you about the potential pitfalls.*

Comment: Hello, thank you but I did that from the very beginning. I didn't mean to have float on there. It was meant to be int. I edited the question but it still doesn't work.

Comment: That does not work either. For the age, when I type 20, it prints out 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the address of the value to `printf`. Get rid of the `&` for all of the arguments you pass to `printf` and the strings you pass to `scanf`. Also as others have said use `%f` for floats or change `age` to be an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error right here:

```
printf("%s %s %s %s %d", &person[0].name, &person[0].dob, &person[0].pob, &person[0].gender, &person[0].age);
```

It should be:

```
printf("%s %s %s %s %d", person[0].name, person[0].dob, person[0].pob, person[0].gender, person[0].age);
```

Because, when you use '&' in the printf function, you are printing the address of the variable and not his value. So remember, you only have to use the '&' to scanf for anything, not to print.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the odd age is that you are outputing the address of person[0].age, not value. printf() takes the value, scanf() takes the address. You also probably meant char* array instead of string object. The code below compiles (although with a few justified warnings), and does print the correct output (tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    int age;
    char name[20], dob[20], pob[20], gender[7];
};

int main ()
{
    person person[10];
    cout << "Please enter your name, date of birth, place of birth, gender, and age, separated by a space.\nFor example, John 1/15/1994 Maine Male 20: ";
    scanf("%s %s %s %s %d", &person[0].name, &person[0].dob, &person[0].pob, &person[0].gender, &person[0].age);
    printf("%s %s %s %s %d", &person[0].name, &person[0].dob, &person[0].pob, &person[0].gender, person[0].age);
    return 0;
}
```